# Working with Visual Studio C++ project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio and I much prefer Visual Studio Code for editing source files.

Is there a way to work with Visual Studio C++ projects in Visual Studio Code? Like getting include paths from ".sln" file or maybe even running MSBuild.

Comment: It's in preview right now, but there are ways: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `Developer Command Prompt/PowerShell for VS 2019`. This will set necessary environment variables such as include paths.
2. Navigate to the directory of your project.
3. Type `code .` to start VS Code in your current directory.

Now, you will be able to use commands like `cl`, `msbuild` etc in the integrated terminal.

Happy coding.

Comment: Oh thanks. MSBuild works, but it seems that I need to configure IntelliSense and problem matcher separately. Or is there some way to synchronize them with .sln?

Comment: @ИльяСамохин Intellisense should work if you have Microsoft C/C++ extension installed. And I'm not sure what you mean by "synchronize them with .sln".

Comment: IntelliSense itself works, but shows many errors, Like some symbol from foo.h is undefined despite foo.h being included.

Comment: I agree with user, Intellisense should work if you have Microsoft C/C++ extension installed. I suggest you could try changing the setting in C/C++ for Intellisense from `Default` to `Tag Parser`.

Comment: @Jeaninez now IntelliSense doesn't show any errors, even if MSBuild fails

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp. As far as I'm concerned, you may have missed some settings.